# How to loop several times within a list?

Tags: python, quantum-computing

I have a code that looks like this,:

```
import random
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

equal_to = {"a":"u_plus", "b":"u_minus", "c":"v_plus", "d":"v_minus"} #bell state

p = 8 #length of generated binary

key1 = [] #list of generated binary 
for i in range(p): 
    temp = random.randint(0,1)
    key1.append(temp) 

tmplist2 = [] #list of random sample_letters
for i in range(p):
    while True:
        attempt = str(random.choice(list(equal_to)))
        tmplist2.append(attempt)

        if attempt == 'b':
            break

#evaluate result of alice binary and bell state
def eva(alice, bell):
    if alice == 1:
        if bell == 'a' or bell == 'b':
            return 1
        elif bell == 'c' or bell == 'd':
            return 0
    elif alice == 0:
        if bell == 'c' or bell == 'd':
            return 1
        elif bell == 'a' or bell == 'b':
            return 0


for_bob = [] #list of generated binary and bell state through logic gate

for k in key1:
    for t in tmplist2:
        e = eva(k, t)
        for_bob.append(e)

#tr = [[eva(k,t) for t in tmplist2] for k in key1] #list comprehension split the key properly
print("generated random binary strings:", key1)
print("generated bell states:", tmplist2)
print("encrypted strings:", for_bob)
```

It printed out something like this:

```
generated random binary strings:
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
generated bell states:
  ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b']
encrypted strings:
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I was looking a way to loop within `tmplist2` without starting again from the beginning, if the string *'b'* came out.

The loop is supposed to function as follows:
`key1[0]` shall evaluate with *'b'*, returning to 0. Since *'b'* came out, outer loop should continue to next element `key1[1]` and it should evaluate with *'c'* and *'b'*, returning 1 0. Again because *'b'* came out, outer loop shall proceed to next element `key[2]` and evaluate itself with *'a'*, *'a'*, *'c'*, and *'b'*, returning 0 0 1 0. This should continue until `tmplist2` finished.

Anyone got solutions for the issue? I was searching the solution of how to loop within a loop and not returning to the beginning when a certain condition is given. In this case *'b'*.

*n.b.: this program was meant to simulate quantum teleportation.*

Comment: Can you send a reference or full text of the problem statement.

Comment: I don't have the problem statement. But basically whenever `key1` (outer loop) evaluates with  'b' (inner loop), the outer loop should move to the next element and continue evaluating until another 'b' was found. As for the result, the length of `for_bob` should be the same as `tmplist2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main data

```
for_bob = []
key1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
tmplist2 = ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b']
```

Approach 1

```
_tmp = tmplist2[:]
for k in key1:
    while _tmp:
        if _tmp[:1] != ['b']:
            for_bob.append(eva(k, *_tmp[:1]))
            _tmp = _tmp[1:]
        else:
            for_bob.append(eva(k, *_tmp[:1]))
            _tmp = _tmp[1:]
            break
```

Approach 2:

```
_tmp = iter(tmplist2)

for i in key1:
    for j in iter(lambda: next(_tmp), None):
        if j != 'b':
            for_bob.append(eva(i, j))
        else:
            for_bob.append(eva(i, j))
            break
```

```
generated random binary strings: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
generated bell states: ['b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b']
encrypted strings: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: on first approach, why does `for_bob.append(eva(k, *_tmp[:1]))` shows `no value argument 'bell' in function call`? other than that it worked as expected. Also tried the second approach but it printed `None`.

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any error. Try change ```*_tmp[:1]``` to ```_tmp[0]```.

Comment: after changing `*_tmp[:1]` to `_tmp[0]` it worked without error.